# Ubuntu 13.10 doesnt detect my nvidia 635m on my laptop

Tags: drivers, nvidia, lenovo

I dont see any other hardware detected in my additional drivers section but my wifi adaptor.In  only detects my intel hd 4000 video card and not my nvidia one how can i fix that ?

Answer (score 0):

You might look up bumblebee or optimus for more detail, but you need to supply a Bus ID for the nvidia hardware in a configuration file.